# Order ul list by span content

Tags: javascript, html, sql-order-by, html-lists

I am really lost with trying to order an ul list by the span in the li.

I have this next structure

```html
<ul id="videosList">
  <li class="response1">
    <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Alex breaking bad</span>
      <li>
        <li class="response1">
          <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Jason playing piano</span>
            <li>
              <li class="response1">
                <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Jenny skying</span>
                  <li>
                    <li class="response1">
                      <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Chuck norris</span>
                        <li>
                          <li class="response1">
                            <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Zyxwaa</span>
                              <li>
                                <li class="response1">
                                  <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Realtek</span>
                                    <li>

                                      <li class="response2">
                                        <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Bad alex breaking</span>
                                          <li>
                                            <li class="response2">
                                              <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Piano playing Jason</span>
                                                <li>
                                                  <li class="response2">
                                                    <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Skying Jenny</span>
                                                      <li>
                                                        <li class="response2">
                                                          <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Norris chuck</span>
                                                            <li>
                                                              <li class="response2">
                                                                <a href="link"><img src="moon" /><span>Intel</span>
                                                                  <li>
</ul>
```

I have that list generated from some uploaded videos and separated because respnse1 brings videos from X database and response brings videos from Y database. What I want to do is to order the list by the content of the SPAN in LI.

I've tried a few things from Google and Stack Overflow but I couldn't adapt any 1 to fit what I need.

So that's it, how can I order a list with JavaScript/jQuery by the content of SPAN in LI?

Comment: Do you have the raw javascript arrays of both video databases? It would be better to combine and sort them before generating the HTML.

Comment: how do you want to order them, alphabetically?

Comment: well, I am using Codeigniter framework so when I send the data to the view I send it as an array ($contentData) which is a multidimensional array (['response1'], ['response2']... and each one with its data. What I do is an foreach for each response and echo an li with the data. Yes I think ordering them alphabetically is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works!...

```
var list = $("ul#videosList");
var desc= false;
list.append(list.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
    var aProp = $(a).find("span").text(),
        bProp = $(b).find("span").text();
    return (aProp > bProp ? 1 : aProp < bProp ? -1 : 0) * (desc ? -1 : 1);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, refer [this extension](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/comment-page-1/#comment-29421) which helps you sorting DOM elements with a custom comparer function. It works like this:

```
$('#videosList').sortElements(function(a, b){
  return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Then, the list items are sorted alphabetically by their captions.

Comment: thank you for your answer you, it didn't work because I was getting a .sortElements it's not a function

Comment: Did you include both jQuery and the linked extension?

Comment: oh lol, I missed that part! LOL, thanks any way but salt's answer works fine for me.