# Reverse jquery function if input checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, if-statement

I have this working function to order a list by the span content

```
var list = $("ul#videosList");
var desc= false;
list.append(list.children().get().sort(function(a, b) {
    var aProp = $(a).find("span").text(),
        bProp = $(b).find("span").text();
    return (aProp > bProp ? 1 : aProp < bProp ? -1 : 0) * (desc ? -1 : 1);
}));
```

which I got it from here: [Order ul list by span content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619233/order-ul-list-by-span-content)

Now my question is, how do I reverse that function if one of the checkboxes is checked? And by reverse I mean to return it to its default state before ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a reference to the original `list.children()` object.

**Update:**

I mean you should keep a reference like:

```
var $orig_order = list.children();
```

before, you make the call to `.get().sort()`. The order of the elements inside `$orig_order` won't change, no matter how they are attached in the DOM. So if you want to restore the original order at some point, you just append them to the list again:

```
list.append($orig_order);
```

Comment: sorry for the delay Felix but I've been busy with other things, could you explain a bit more if you don't mind?

Comment: I clarified my answer, I hope it helps :)